Intercept XHR request
I am currently facing the problem of wanting to read 4 values from a page where I only have one initial URL. When this is called up, an Authentication HTTP-only cookie is created on the server (valid for approx. 4 days), which is saved in the browser memory. Next, a forward to another URL is executed, which contains the previously received cookie in the header and successfully reads the data. Since HTTP-only cookies cannot be read out on the client side via script, I am now wondering how I can read out the data cleanly without having to scrape the entire DOM afterwards. In other words, I only want to use the second request (XHL) to extract the data cleanly from the JSON response. The whole thing should be executed on an ESP32 that only knows the initial URL.
Does anyone have an idea how to implement this?
